# 17 letters, 4 groups

Tags: pattern, letters, connect-wall

Arrange these 17 letters into four groups of four:

B, A, N, X, O, V, AB, Q, Z, J, I, L, S, C, W, E

[image: 17 letters arranged in a 4x4 grid]

This is inspired by the [New York Times Connections](https://www.nytimes.com/games/connections) puzzles.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the connecting groups here are:

> **Group 1: Blood types** (A, B, AB, O)
>
>  **Group 2: Compass points** (N, E, S, W)
>
>  **Group 3: Scrabble tiles scoring 8+ points** (Z, Q, J, X)
>
>  **Group 4: Roman numerals** (C, V, I, L)
>
>  ('X' is a red herring for the Roman numeral grouping)